# Google's SMTP server doesn't respond besides the first message

Tags: node.js, smtp

```
  const conn = net.connect(25, "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", () => {
    console.log("connected!");
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        conn.write(Buffer.from("HELO gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"), () => {
          console.log("sent");
        }),
      2000
    );
  });

  conn.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("data:", data.toString());
  });
```

The above yields nothing besides the initial `220 mx.google.com ESMTP w13si2457930ply.145 - gsmtp`. However, doing the same via `netcat` does work. In Wireshark, the HELO messages are the same, aside of things like TCP checksums and whatnot.

What could be wrong here? How even to begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Newline is required at the end:

```
Buffer.from("HELO gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com\n")
```